# What is the name of this flowering plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

My mother is in hospice, and this beautiful flower is outside her window. She would like to know the name of "her" flower.

The flower is growing in Eastern Kansas and we are approaching the first day of summer here

[image]

Comment: Where's it growing? What's the season there? Can you add more pictures of the plant (close-ups)? See [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a variety of [canna lily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canna_(plant)). There are several flowers that have opened on the tip of your plant, as in the photo below.

[image]

Comment: The flower is growing in Eastern Kansas and we are approaching the first day of summer here.   I will try and post better pictures of the flower and its leaves.  Thank you all very much for the help so far.